# Getting an error while using Tabbed activity in Android

Tags: java, android

Error is -
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/widget/TintManager;**

My code snippet is -

```
public class TaberActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    //This is our tablayout
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    //This is our viewPager
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_taber);

        //Adding toolbar to the activity
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Initializing the tablayout
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        //Initializing viewPager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        //Creating our pager adapter
        Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        //Adding adapter to pager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

I'm unable to figure out where I'm going wrong. It'll be of a great help if some one can suggest me the solutions to this.

EDIT - 
Have the following Gradle script :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.avidprogrammers.atlantiquemoney"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Have the above gradle in the application.

Comment: post your `gradle` too

Comment: Show your build gradle dependencies

Comment: clean project or invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Updated! @pleft

Comment: Updated! @EpicPandaForce

Comment: That didn't work. Tried all such things. App gets crashed after getting installed on phone @AmrishKakadiya

Comment: Post xml of Tabs

Comment: I have a Relative layout with a textview in it. I don't think it is related to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your appcompat dependency version are mismatched. You use v26 and v23 together.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

You should change cardview and design to use 26.x.y as well.

Answer (score 1):

Update your `support` dependencies to the latest ones:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
```

instead of this

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Replace your Gradel with this

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.avidprogrammers.atlantiquemoney"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    complie 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```